# MySQL get blocks of consecutive numbers in a table

Tags: php, mysql

Table name: list

Column names: NPA, nxx, xxxx

Objective: table consists of thousands of entries. I want to search and get let's say 100 xxxx's in consecutive order for a specific npa, nxx.

Xxxx values range from 0001 to 9999. However some numbers in that range do not exist. Hence I want to find the first block of continuous 100 numbers.

I have tried several methods provided in some of the suggestions and solutions for similar questions but none seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I should further mention that this is an older script and MySQL version where I am using mysql (deprecated ) and not mysqli or pdo

Comment: Please add what you have, what you tried, and how it performed. Also clarify how PHP is related, if it isn't please remove the tag.

Comment: Here is what I have so far, which only returns the first 100 results by id column as opposed to xxxx

$query="SELECT *
FROM list
WHERE 100 = (SELECT count(*) 
           FROM list
           WHERE xxxx
           BETWEEN xxxx AND (xxxx + 100 - 1)
           ) LIMIT 1";

Comment: Should just be `SELECT * FROM list LIMIT $offset, $nr_of_records_to_show ORDER BY xxxx ASC`. The offset would be where to start and number of records the amount to retrieve. So for first 100 it would `0, 99`, for the next 100 it would be `100, 199`.

Comment: But that would not return the first 100 consecutive xxxx's. It will just return the first 100, regardless.

Comment: Is 100 the upper limit - what happens if the 100 is in a block of over 100?

Comment: Let's say instead that you want the first 5 consecutive numbers from a data set of say 30. Now see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by allocating block and row numbers using variables for example if I am looking for the first block of 2 consecutive numbers

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T (NXX VARCHAR(1), XXX INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
('A',1),('A',3),('A',4),('A',6),('A',7),('A',8),
('b',1),('b',2),('b',3),('b',4),('b',5),('b',6);

select x.nxx,x.xxx from
(
select s.nxx,min(s.block) block
from
(
SELECT T.NXX,T.XXX,
         IF(T.NXX <> @PNXX OR T.XXX > @PXXX + 1 ,@B:=@B+1,@B:=@B) BLOCK,
         IF(T.NXX <> @PNXX OR T.XXX > @PXXX + 1 ,@RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,
         if(@rn = 2,@lim:=1,@lim:=0) lim,
         @PNXX:= T.NXX PNXX,
         @PXXX:= T.XXX PXXX
FROM T
CROSS JOIN(SELECT @RN:=0,@B:=0,@PNXX:='', @PXXX:=0,@lim:=0) R
ORDER BY T.NXX,T.XXX
) s 
where s.lim = 1
group by s.nxx
) w
join
(
SELECT T.NXX,T.XXX,
         IF(T.NXX <> @PNXX_1 OR T.XXX > @PXXX_1 + 1 ,@B1:=@B1+1,@B1:=@B1) BLOCK,
         IF(T.NXX <> @PNXX_1 OR T.XXX > @PXXX_1 + 1 ,@RN1:=1,@RN1:=@RN1+1) RN,
         if(@rn1 = 2,@lim1:=1,@lim1:=0) lim,
         @PNXX_1:= T.NXX PNXX,
         @PXXX_1:= T.XXX PXXX
FROM T
CROSS JOIN(SELECT @RN1:=0,@B1:=0,@PNXX_1:='', @PXXX_1:=0,@lim1:=0) R
ORDER BY T.NXX,T.XXX
) x on x.block = w.block and x.rn <= 2
order by x.block,x.nxx,x.xxx;
```

Where the sub query s works out the blocks and whether 2 consecutive numbers have been reached, then the min block for a nxx is derived and joined to another sub query which plucks the required blocks

```
+------+------+
| nxx  | xxx  |
+------+------+
| A    |    3 |
| A    |    4 |
| b    |    1 |
| b    |    2 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.23 sec)
```